# Is it true that --quiet is not uniformly supported throughout git?

Tags: git

I am trying to write a script in which I suppress all git output and dispatch based on error code.

However it seems like there's no single way to do that. It seems that --quiet doesn't work everywhere. But that seems hard to believe. So I wonder if I am doing something incorrect.

Comment: Well you could always take the sledgehammer approach, and just redirect stdout/err to `/dev/null`.

Comment: Agreed. I was trying to avoid sledge :)